# How to create a new column from other column by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
enterhigh    exithigh        buy_action                                                
4149.99      4044.00         1.0
4211.08      4068.50        -1.0
4041.23      3750.08         1.0
4265.80      4103.51        -1.0
4250.94      4136.33         1.0
```

and I hope I can create a new column by buy_action's value, if buy_action is 1, new column

```
enterhigh    exithigh        buy_action   action_price                                                
4149.99      4044.00         1.0          4149.99
4211.08      4068.50        -1.0          4068.50
4041.23      3750.08         1.0          4041.23
4265.80      4103.51        -1.0          4103.51
4250.94      4136.33         1.0          4250.94
```

will take enterhigh, if it's -1, take exithigh

I tried using numpy select like

```
condition = ((df['buy_action'] == 1),
             (df['buy_action'] == -1))
value = [df['enterhigh'],df['exithigh']]
df['action_price'] = np.select(condition,value)
```

but it's not working

Thank you for your helping!!

Comment: How numpy select is not working? please explain.

Comment: actually I think it would work if I understand numpy select more, when I code the code above , the action_price was filled by zero at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
df["action_price"] = np.where(df.buy_action == 1, df.enterhigh, df.exithigh)
```

It takes values from `enter_high` if `buy_action` is `1`, else it takes from `exit_high`.

And we get

```
                date  enterhigh  exithigh  buy_action  action_price
2017-08-20  06:00:00    4149.99   4044.00         1.0       4149.99
2017-08-20  23:00:00    4211.08   4068.50        -1.0       4068.50
2017-08-22  17:00:00    4041.23   3750.08         1.0       4041.23
2017-08-23  19:00:00    4265.80   4103.51        -1.0       4103.51
2017-08-24  21:00:00    4250.94   4136.33         1.0       4250.94
```

Note that any value of `buy_action` that is not `1` (e.g. `-1`, `2`) will yield values from `exithigh`.

Comment: Sure, I am new here, I hope I have done it in a right way, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good use case for the apply method, that'll take a row and returns a new value :

```py
df["action_price"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.enterhigh if x.buy_action == 1 else x.exithigh, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
df['new column'] = [df.loc[i, 'exithigh'] for i in df.index if df.loc[i, 'buy_action']>0 else -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy select`:

```
df['action_price'] = np.select([df.buy_action.eq(1)], [df.enterhigh], default=df.exithigh)
```